# how to scale image using scalecontroler

Tags: fabricjs

I cannot scale the image when moving the scale controller. It shows the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: canvas.requestRenderAll is not a function
```

Can please anyone help to solve this problem? I want the functionality to be implemented for image please refer to [this](http://fabricjs.com/controls). Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Instagram</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="fabric.js-1.7.21/dist/fabric.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <body>
        <canvas id="c" width="500px" height="400px"></canvas>
        <div id="range">
        <input type="range" class="image-scale-lever" step="0.1" max="3" min="0.1" value="1" id="scale-control"></label>
      </div>
      <script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
          fabric.Image.fromURL('locket.png', function(oImg) {
            oImg.set({
          left: 0,
          top: 0,
          width:500,
          height:400
        });
            canvas.add(oImg);

             var scaleControl = $('#scale-control');
                   scaleControl.oninput = function(x) {
        this.val(x);
        oImg.scale(parseFloat(x)).setCoords();
        canvas.requestRenderAll();
              }

     function updateControls() {
                  scaleControl.oninput(oImg.scaleX);                          
            }

            canvas.observe("object:scaling", function (e) {
            updateControls();
    });
    });


    });


  [1]: https://withyoulockets.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/image/700x700/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe/k/a/katieopen1100px-min.png
```

Comment: requestRenderAll is introduced after version 2.x

Comment: durga can u make changes to code and rectify the mistake....the image should scale  when i increase the scale controller and viceversa...

Answer (score 0):

Here is the result. You need to change the scale of the object on onchange event callback.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <title>Instagram</title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.21/fabric.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" >
  jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
        var canvas = this.__canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
          fabric.Image.fromURL('https://withyoulockets.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/image/700x700/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe/k/a/katieopen1100px-min.png', function(oImg) {
            oImg.set({
          left: 0,
          top: 0,
          width:500,
          height:400
        });
            canvas.add(oImg);

             var scaleControl = $('#scale-control');
                   scaleControl.on("change",function() {

         var newValue = this.value; 

        oImg.scale(parseFloat(newValue)).setCoords();
        canvas.renderAll();
              })

              function updateControls() {
                  scaleControl.oninput(oImg.scaleX);                          
            }

            canvas.observe("object:scaling", function (e) {
            updateControls();
    });
    });


    });
</script>
      <body>
        <canvas id="c" width="500px" height="400px"></canvas>
        <div id="range">
        <input type="range" class="image-scale-lever" step="0.1" max="3" min="0.1" value="1" id="scale-control"></label>
      </div>
```

Check here:
https://jsfiddle.net/3mjhxcyn/2/